# Always included data irrespective of filter in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am building a (pivot) grid in Tableau and want to always include a data point (a row in the fetched dataset) in the resultant view, irrespective of any filters the user selects. Is this possible?

Comment: Set up the user permissions of the published workbook to disallow filtering.

Comment: No, I do want to them to be able to filter, just want this one row to be included always.